# Accessing Styles from outside angular project

Tags: css, angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am working on an angular project, where I am having my all the CSS files under "styles" folder. Styles configuration in angular.json is as follows:

```
  "styles": [
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ]
```

In angular component, I am accessing styles as follows:

```
  styleUrls: ['./../../../styles/style1.css']
```

CSS are getting applied when inside project. But I want to remove my CSS files form styles folder and place  them at location external to project for example at "C:\Users\Style\". And want to access styles from this folder in my angular project. I tried to do that by giving C drive path in styleurls and changing path in styles in angular.json. But that is not working. Is there is any way I can do it?

Comment: That does not sound like a good idea. Why do you need that?

Comment: I know that's not a good idea but I have been asked try this and I am not getting how to do this